# Why can't python socket resolve domain name here?

Tags: python, sockets, dns, hosts

I'm using python socket to connect to a server for logging purpose. The IP address of the server is `x.x.x.x` (I just hide this, `x` can be number from 0 to 255) and, and my domain name could be `www.example.domain.com`. I've written this `x.x.x.x www.example.domain.com` in `/etc/hosts` with `sudo` access. However, when I tried to use the domain name in my program, python socket just failed to resolve the domain name.

```
import socket

mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
'''Block of code'''
mysocket.sendto('Hello!', 'www.example.domain.com')
mysocket.close()
```

The error message here is:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not
>   known

If I change `www.example.domain.com` to a plain text host name such as `testLogger`, python socket is able to resolve that. I can `ping` the domain name on my machine, so I'm just wondering why python socket can't resolve the domain name in this scenario.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What happens when you do `socket.gethostbyname('www.example.domain.com')`?

Comment: In your updated code, the address in sendto() is a string, not a tuple - and it's missing a port number as well.

Comment: @birryree It will be able to resolve the domain string.

Comment: @DanielleM. It's a typo, I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several mistakes:

You're using a UDP socket primitive `sendto()` on an IP socket.
Also, the format of the address parameter is incorrect, it usually is a tuple (hostname, port).

So, either create a proper UDP socket:

```
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mysocket.sendto(b'data', ('hostname', 9999))
```

or use `connect` + `send`/`sendall` instead:

```
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(('hostname', 9999))
mysocket.sendall(b'data')
```

Comment: Ok, so just another general question, is `python3 socket` able to resolve domain name by default?

Comment: and yes, they do this, as it is usually handled at the operating system level where the socket API calls are processed